# Attaching files from a Private folder with Mandrill

Tags: emails

I have working code that will send attachments programmatically through Mandrill .

I'm changing the folder to 'private' now ; since doing so the attachment doesn't work.

this is what the code was

```
$cvpath = 'sites/default/files/cv/'.$cv_filename;

$message['attachments'][] = drupal_realpath($cvpath);
```

this stopped working .

I've tried

```
$cvpath = 'private://sites/default/files/cv/'.$cv_filename;

$message['attachments'][] = file_create_url($cvpath);
```

but this didn't work.

The email send with no errors, but also no attachment.

On testing the file_create_url creates a full url like 'http://example.com/system/files/filename.php'

the folder 'system/files' doesn't exist.

In administration > config > media > file system

for private folder I have.

/sites/default/private-folder

Any ideas on a way around getting mandrill to send from a private folder welcome.

Comment: "didn't work" is most common, and most useless "bugreport" in IT. What exactly happened? Was message sent? How did it look like? What error message appeared on your screen? What is in logs?

Comment: many apologies Mołot

> Email sends with no attachment. 
> no error message.

Comment: I've edited with more information.